# Worklight 6.1 - How to refresh content after upload new wlapp in mobile webapp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have been working on MobileWebapp and found that after every upload of wlapp , we need to clear the cache on browser to check new changes. Is there any thing which needs to configure at server end to reload new change if newly deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored the application manifest feature for Mobile Web apps? See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_appcache_procedure.html?lang=en